# Java Spring Multiple @Autowired MongoRepository Usages with JWT

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security

The successfulAuthentication function in JWTAuthenticationFilter.java gives a nullpointerexception. Do you see why this would be an issue? Is it a problem with using the same bean for autowiring?

This is my current project structure:

```
-com
  -register
    -RegisterController.java
  -security
    -JWTAuthenticationFilter.java
    -JWTAuthorizationFilter.java
    -SecurityConstants.java
    -WebSecurity.java
  -user
    -User.java
    -UserRepository.java
    -UserService.java
  -Application.java
```

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  @Bean
  public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
      return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
  User findByUsername(String name);
  User findByEmail(String Email);
  User findBy_id(ObjectId id);
}
```

UserService.java

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = this.userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if(user == null)
        return null;
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user"));
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
  }

  public User getUserByUsername(String username) {
    return this.userRepository.findByUsername(username);
  }

  public User getUserBy_id(ObjectId _id) {
    return userRepository.findBy_id(_id);
  }

  public void saveUser(User newUser){
    userRepository.save(newUser);
  }
}
```

User.java

```
@Document
public final class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private ObjectId _id;
  private String email;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private AccountProperties accountProperties;
  private Address address;
  private List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
  private String phoneNumber;

  public User() {}

  public User(@JsonProperty("email") String email, @JsonProperty("username") String username,
            @JsonProperty("password") String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String get_id() { return _id.toHexString();}

  getters and setters() ...
}
```

JWTAuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepo;
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        User creds = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(req.getInputStream(), User.class);

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword(),
                        new ArrayList<>())
        );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                        HttpServletResponse res,
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String username = ((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();

    String token = JWT.create()
            .withSubject(username)
            .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
            .sign(HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()));
    res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    User u = uRepo.findByUsername("admin");
    res.getWriter().write(
            "{\"" + SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING + "\":\"" + SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX+token + "\"," +
            "\"" + "ObjectID" + "\":\"" + u.get_id() + "\"}"
    );
  }
}
```

JWTAuthorizationFilter.java

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

  public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    super(authManager);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                HttpServletResponse res,
                                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

    if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        return;
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }

  private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
    if (token != null) {
        // parse the token.
        String user = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()))
                .build()
                .verify(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                .getSubject();

        if (user != null) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        return null;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

WebSecurity.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  private UserService userDetailsService;
  @Autowired
  private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS );
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {auth.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(this.bCryptPasswordEncoder);}

  @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
  }
}
```

SecurityConstants.java

```
public class SecurityConstants {
  public static final String SECRET = "SecretKeyToGenJWTs";
  public static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 864_000_000; // 10 days
  public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
  public static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";
  public static final String SIGN_UP_URL = "/users/sign-up";
}
```

RegisterController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class RegisterController {
  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;
  @Autowired
  private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

  @PostMapping("/sign-up")
  public void signUp(@RequestBody User user) {
    if (user.getPassword() == null || user.getUsername() == null)
        return;
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userService.saveUser(user);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the root cause of your issue, but I have never seen `@Configuration` in the main application. I would try to move that to a separate config class and see if that helps

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Java Spring, so do you know whether we need a config class? And if so, would the WebSecurity class be fine to annotate with @Configuration?

Comment: You should be able to add the `@Configuration` to the WebSecurity class, I have that in one of my team's java projects. My IDE will complain if I use `@Autowired` inside a class annotated with `@Configuration` though, so that may not work in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you doesn't define JWTAuthenticationFilter as `Bean`, so spring doesn't inject dependencies in it.

You can get beans in filter manualy. From the GenericFilterBean javadoc:

> This generic filter base class has no dependency on the Spring org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext concept. Filters usually don't load their own context but rather access service beans from the Spring root application context, accessible via the filter's ServletContext (see org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils).

Or you can make it bean. But if you are using Spring Boot consider that:

> The fact that all filters internal to Spring Security are unknown to the container is important, especially in a Spring Boot application, where all @Beans of type Filter are registered automatically with the container by default. So if you want to add a custom filter to the security chain, you need to either not make it a @Bean or wrap it in a FilterRegistrationBean that explicitly disables the container registration.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate the JWTAuthenticationFilter with @Component or add @Bean in configuration file . Looks like the object is not created